# Is it possible to reverse my choice on the moderator election?

Tags: support, election

I'm currently viewing on mobile (with show desktop site selected) and as I was flitting around the candidates statements I pressed my first choice by accident.

Its not the end of the world if it's irreversible as I'm confident in all of the candidates abilities.

Is it possible to reverse my action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, just click on the first choice by a different person, and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I didn't want to try anything else in case I buggered it up further. Once again, SE has covered all potential issues. SE rocks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, although maybe *not* on mobile.

If you'd have been browsing non-mobile, you'd have seen a notification afterwards explaining that you can change your selected candidates any time until the election ends.

Comment: Yh I didn't see the message you mention. I'm using the desktop site on mobile so I can't complain if anything isn't working the way it should. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Dominic I've never heard of someone using the mobile version of a site on desktop; did I understand that right?

Comment: No lol, I said I'm using the desktop site on my mobile. The other way round just wouldn't make sense.

Comment: I mean, if you like simple, fat layouts, you could code that browser. Or modify chrome.

Comment: (Stupidest idea I've had so far today)